# Redirect from a naked domain to www strips query string params

Tags: redirect, heroku, dns, cname, a-records

I've got my domain set up on iwantmyname.com and hosted by Heroku.  There's a CNAME record pointing to example.herokuapp.com and the naked http://example.com redirects to http://www.example.com.  That was fine until I realized that the redirect from the naked to the www strips off any query string parameters like important referral information.

How can I set it up properly so I'm not losing this information?  I don't care whether the naked domain actually redirects to the www or just displays the normal page (e.g. it's fine if http://example.com/somepath shows up in the url bar instead of redirecting to http://www.example.com/somepath like it does now).

Comment: How are you handling the redirect from the naked domain to www.example.com? Also, have you taken a look at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#root-domain and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains ?

Comment: I think this might help you http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect